# Вероятность нахождения блока Bitcoin

Tags: алгоритм, теория-вероятностей

Может кто знает где достать алгоритм или рассчитать вероятность нахождения блока. Хочу посчитать эффективность пула и свою долю в общих вычислениях

Есть:

1. общая мощность пула ($poolHashRate)
2. мощность конкретного воркера ($myHashRate)
3. сложность сети ($difficulty)
4. мощность сети ($networkHashRate)

Общее количество возможных вычисляемых блоков можно посчитать так

```
$hashTime = ((float)$difficulty) * (pow(2, 32) / ($poolHashRate * 1000));
$blocksPerDay = (24 * 3600) / $hashTime;
```

Но какова вероятность того что пул не найдёт блок? При условии что ничего в матрице не меняется, и все переменные не меняются во времени.